# How to stop or terminate a job after 02:00 AM

Tags: jobs, termination, autosys

I want to terminate a job after running until a particular time, but I should not specify a date.

I know `sendevent -E KILLJOB -J job name -T "mm/dd/yy HH:mm`, but this has a date also to be specified. But for my requirement, I don't need a date. Can someone help me how to achieve this?
Thanks,
Hema

Comment: Where are you sending the event from? This might be a question for the Super User subsite if it’s more relevant to system administration.

Comment: It is in autosys using a job I want to run that command

Answer (score 1):

If **sendevent** is being as  command attribute for a CMD job type.

The owner must have access to the Autosys DB and not just to regular machine where jobs run.
Please check the machine / owner privilages to do so.

The other way through autosys attributes.

Consider the job starts at HH:mm hour of the day.
Then the minutes between HH:mm and 02:00 to be assigned for **term_run_time** attribute in the job.

Once the job starts, it would terminate after those minutes if not completed.

Example:
Job start time is 16:00

Between 16:00 and 02:00 there are 10 hours = 600 minutes

> term_run_time: 600

This 600 minutes is relative to starting time.
In autosys there is no attribute to terminate a job at an absolute time.

Hope this helps